# Javascript validation issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I having some trouble validating some fields with javascript.  I'm trying to test a field called name of 30 characters max, John Smith, Paul M'Dougall Laura-Jane should all test true but gazz8932 should test false.

The EAID should be up to 16 characters 123kjg-34_dfs should test true but wil *&$ etc it should test false.

Finally the url should be from youtube.com or ea.com but I can't bet any of these to work.

If any light can be shed it would be much appreciated...

```
// create the errors array
var errors = false;

// clean last errors
$('#goalsubmission p.error').remove();
$('#goalsubmission .error').removeClass('error');

// test the name
var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]{0,30}/i;
var name = $('#goalsubmission input#name');
if(reg.test(name.val()) == false){
    name.parent().addClass('error');
    errors == true;
    name.parent().append('<p class="error">Make sure you have put your name using only letters and spaces.</p>');
} else {
    name.parent().removeClass('error');
}

/*
// test the email
var reg = /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/;
var email = $('#goalsubmission input#email');
var result = reg.test(email.val());
if(email.val().length == 0 || result == false){
    email.parent().addClass('error');
    errors == true;
    email.parent().append('<p class="error">Make sure you have entered a valid email address.</p>');
} else {
    email.parent().removeClass('error');
}
*/

// test the ea id
var reg = /^[a-z0-9-_]{0,16}/i;
var eaid = $('#goalsubmission input#eaid');
if(reg.test(eaid.val()) == false){
    eaid.parent().addClass('error');
    errors == true;
    eaid.parent().append('<p class="error">Make sure you have entered a valid EAID.</p>');
} else {
    eaid.parent().removeClass('error');
}

// test the url
var regYT = /^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?v=\w+(&\S*)?$/
var regEA = /^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?ea.com\/?$/
var url = $('#goalsubmission input#url');
if(
//                          url.val().length == 0 || 
//                          url.val().length > 255  || 
    (regYT.test(url.val()) == false && regEA.test(url.val()) == false)
){
    url.parent().addClass('error');
    errors == true;
    url.parent().append('<p class="error">Make sure you have entered a valid Url, from either YouTube or EA.</p>');
} else {
    url.parent().removeClass('error');
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the rules that say why `gazz8932` or `*&$` are no valid matches?

Comment: /^[a-z ,.'-]{0,30}/i as far as I understand say, from start of string case insensitive of length 0-30 chars looking for a-z spaces, commas, fullstops, hyphens and quotation marks.  Is this not the case?  There is no mention of numbers so it should test false if there are numbers correct?

Comment: Yes. I see the source of my misunderstanding: you're asking three questions in one. Maybe better split up the question, focusing on one regex each. Even better to first search this site since questions like these have been asked dozens of times before.

Comment: I got everything working using the solution below.  As for the urls I used the following: var reg = /(youtube.com|ea.com)/; if(reg.test(url.val()) == false) etc

Comment: Better escape the dot or your regex will hit on something like `tearcompany.info`. Also, use word boundaries, or you'll mistakenly match `tea.com` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the regex with **`$`** at the end, so that it doesn't match anything further from the expression. This way, you'll match `"Paul"`, but not `"Paul123"` with the following expression:

```
var reg = /^[a-z ,.'-]{0,30}$/i;
```

Same thing happens with `eai`:

```
var reg = /^[a-z0-9-_]{0,16}$/i;
```

Comment: No, the uppercase letters are included (`/i` modifier).